# Object doesn't support this property or method 438 in vba outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Am new to VBA Macro. i have a VBA Macro **(I have modified lot in these Macro)** which will get the mail detail(Subject,Sender,Occurrence) in given specific time range. The Macro is working fine when getting mail of last 30 minutes. But when increasing the time range like 1 hr 30 min,   I am getting the error of Object doesn't support this property or method  438. Could you please assist. Below is the script. I am getting the error in the following line '**If TypeName(myitem) = "MailItem" And Not (myitem.Sender Is Nothing) Then**

```
'Declare variables needed
    Dim i As Long, k As Long: i = 2
    k = 1
'Get Mailbox Name from User for naming Excel Workbook
    Dim excelName As Variant
    Dim mydaet1 As Date, mydate As Date
    Dim iFolder As Long
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    mydate1 = Now
    mydate = Now + TimeSerial(0, -90, 0)



    excelName = "Example_Mail_Count"
'Delete the excel file if already exists
    If Dir("C:\Temp\" + excelName + ".xlsx") <> "" Then
        MsgBox "A file with name " + excelName + ".xlsx already exists in C:\Temp\ Folder. Take backup, if needed. It will be deleted now."
        Kill "C:\Temp\" + excelName + ".xlsx"
        MsgBox "Excel File Deleted!"
    End If
'Create instance for Excel
    Set objXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With objXl
        .Visible = False
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
'Create instance for Outlook
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    iFolder = 1
'Create a new Excel Workbook
    Set xlworkbook = objXl.Workbooks.Add
    With xlworkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Temp\" + excelName + ".xlsx"
    End With
    xlworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    'Header for the report
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = "Subject"
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = "Sender"
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = "Occurrences"

    'Add other fields here as needed
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Font.Bold = True

    Do While True

            Select Case iFolder
                Case 1: Set olFldr = objnSpace.Folders("First_Mail_Box").Folders("Inbox")
                        xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k) = "First"
                        xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(k).Font.Bold = True
                Case 2: Set olFldr = objnSpace.Folders("Sec_Mail_box").Folders("Inbox")
                        i = i + 1
                        xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = "Second"
                        xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Font.Bold = True

                Case Else: Exit Do
            End Select

'Display dialog box to select outlook folder
     Set myItemsTemp = olFldr.Items
'Filter emails and Sort by Subject
    '****!!!!Update the date interval as needed****!!!!
    Set myItems = myItemsTemp.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >='" & Format(mydate, "ddddd hh:nn AMPM") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(mydate1, "ddddd hh:nn AMPM") & "' ")


    myItems.Sort "[Subject]"

'Loop through each email item in the folder selected
    For Each myitem In myItems
        If TypeName(myitem) = "MailItem" And Not (myitem.Sender Is Nothing) Then
            i = i + 1
            xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = myitem.Subject
            xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = myitem.Sender
            k = i
    Else
        i = i + 1
            xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = myitem.Subject
            xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = myitem.SenderName
            k = i

        End If
    Next myitem
'Count instances and remove duplicates
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C[-2],RC[-2],C[-1],RC[-1])"
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C" & i).Value = xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C" & i).Value
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$C$" & i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 50
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 35
    xlworkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 20

    iFolder = iFolder + 1


    Loop
'Save and close the workbook
    xlworkbook.Save
    MsgBox "*************************************Done*************************************" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Generated Report  " + excelName + ".xlsx file in C:\Temp\ Folder. Take Backup or Leave it"
    'xlworkbook.Close
    xlworkbook.Activate
    objXl.Visible = True

'Exit Excel Application

'Deallocate all instances
    Set myItemsTemp = Nothing
    Set myItems = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set NS = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objXl = Nothing

'Finish it up
   ' MsgBox "*************************************Done*************************************" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Please view " + excelName + ".xlsx file in C:\Temp\ Folder for the report."
    'Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\Temp\", vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If TypeName(myitem) = "MailItem" And Not (myitem.Sender Is Nothing) Then
```

You need to put these two tests as different If blocks

```
If TypeName(myitem) = "MailItem" Then
    If Not (myitem.Sender Is Nothing) Then

    End If
End if
```

The reason you need to do it that way is that in VBA the `And` doesn't "short-circuit" - even if the item is not a mail item (so the first part of the test is `False`), the second part of the test is still run, and so the item may not have a `Sender` property, which would raise the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi Tim, It is worked, how to close(unable to delete) the existing excel sheet force fully. because it giving the error as permission denied(file is opened) when the excel file is deleting from the code on next run. What i am doing(temprory solution) is going to the task manger and find the particular process and killing it

Comment: you should open a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Thank you so much